# Example of a proper surjection to Hausdorff space that is not perfect?

Tags: general-topology, continuity, compactness, closed-map

Use the definitions:

- A continuous map is **perfect** if it is a closed surjection with compact fibers.
- A continuous map is **proper** if the inverse image of each compact set is compact. (In contrast to Bourbaki's more general definition, according to which a map $f : X \rightarrow Y$ is proper when, for every topological space $Z$, the product map $f \times i_{Z}: X \times Z \rightarrow Y \times Z$ is closed.)

The posts (1) [Proper map not closed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/966250/proper-map-not-closed/966258#966258), (2) [A continuous surjection is proper if and only if pre-images of compact sets are compact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2573289/a-continuous-surjection-is-proper-if-and-only-if-pre-images-of-compact-sets-are), (3) [$f$ proper but not universally closed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1347788/f-proper-but-not-universally-closed/1347806#1347806), and (4) [Proper map not closed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/966250/proper-map-not-closed/966258#966258) present examples of continuous surjections that are proper but not perfect (which amounts to saying they are not closed). However, in each of these examples the codomain $Y$ fails to be a Hausdorff space.

Is there such an example where $Y$ *is* a Hausdorff space? (Of course, for such an example, $Y$ could not be locally compact or, more generally, compactly generated.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X$ be an uncountable discrete space and $Y$ be its one-point Lindelöfication: $Y = X \cup \{\infty\}$ and a neighbourhood of $\infty$ is of the form $\{\infty\} \cup X\setminus C$, where $C \subseteq X$ is countable, while any subset of $X$ is still open. An alternative definition is $C$ is closed in $Y$ if $\infty \in C$ or $C \subseteq X$ and $C$ is at most countable.

$Y$ is also called [Fortissimo space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fort_space) in counterexamples in topology.

Then as an example: let $Z=Y$ as sets, but in the discrete topology, and $Y$ is the above space, $f:Z \to Y$ is the identity function, which is continuous as the domain is discrete; not closed (as the topology on $Y$ is strictly coarser than the discrete one) and proper as the only compact subsets of $Y$ are the finite ones, and these have compact pre-images. $Y$ is hereditarily normal ($T_5$), so certainly at least Hausdorff.

$Y$ indeed cannot be a $k$-space, as a proper map onto a Hausdorff $k$-space is perfect by a classical theorem.

Comment: Description of the two spaces needs a bit of revision, as you want $X$ and $Y$ to have the same underlying set. Let $S$ be an uncountable set and let $p \in S$ be a particular point. Let $X$ be $S$ with its discrete topology. Let $Y$ be the space obtained by giving $S$ the "Fortissimo topology": a subset $U$ of $S$ is open for $Y$ if and only if $S \setminus U$ is countable or $p \notin U$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $Y$ be any Hausdorff space that is not compactly generated, and let $X$ be the $k$-ification of $Y$ (so $X$ has the same underlying set and a set is closed in $X$ iff its intersection with each compact subset of $Y$ is closed).  Then the identity map $X\to Y$ is continuous and surjective, and is proper since the topology on $X$ is the same as the topology on $Y$ when restricted to any compact set.  However, it is not a closed map, since if it were then it would be a homeomorphism and $Y$ would be compactly generated.

Comment: My example is an instance of this construction, I see. I just realised.